# What does the term 'convex' mean, when we say 'convex cone'.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-geometry, convex-cone

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone):

> A convex cone is a a subset of a vector space that is closed under linear combinations with positive coefficients.

I wonder if the term 'convex' has a special meaning or geometric interpretation. Therefore, my question is: why we call it 'convex'?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set

Comment: Convex means convex in the sense of subsets of a real vector space.

Comment: Another way to think about it is: a convex cone $C$ is a cone (that is $a C \subset C$ for all $a \ge 0$) that is also a convex set.

Comment: I remember the first time being introduced to the word "convex" and "concave" was as a small child [being shown lenses](https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-convex-and-concave-lens.html).  It wasn't until much later that I learned a formal definition of the terms, but the intuitive definition matches just fine, whether something bends "outward" or bends "inward."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set of points is convex if the line segment connecting any two points of the set lies entirely in the set.  You'd think of a shape as "concave" if you could connect two points by a line segment and part of that line segment was outside the set.  So "convex" means "non concave".

Comment: You start out by giving a definition of "convex", which is correct. It is non correct when you conclude by saying it means "non concave". It means the same, but is a bit circular as "concave" means "not convex".

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity  I'm giving an intuitive answer here, which is what the OP wants.  Teaching math and doing math are not the same things.

Comment: In operational research literature, "concave", when applied to a function, means "the opposite function is convex". So "convex means non concave" is false: a function like sinus is neither concave nor convex. This is also the definition in Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni 1. OP asked about cones, not functions.  2. I gave the correct definition.  3.  I said "not" not "non."  4.  The final comment is not given as a formal definition, but to help the OP see what the opposite of the definition does.  5.  I hope you're not a teacher.  6.  I wonder what is wrong with people like you.

Comment: @B.Goddard I am a teacher from time to time, yes, at undergraduate level. ;-) I was surprised how harsh was your reply. But never mind.